# How to determine sample size for number of pairwise comparisons for item ranking

Tags: statistical-significance, ranking

Suppose I have 100 items and I would like to come up with their ranking based on user preferences. i.e. each item should receive a rank from between 1-100, where 1 is the most preferred item and 100 is the least preferred item. Data is collected through pairwise comparisons, where users choose which item they prefer (boolean). Out of these comparison a final ranking will be determined. How do I rigorously determine the number of pairwise comparisons I need per item, to produce a "statistically significant" ranking? I am less interested in how the ranking is constructed and more interested in determining a suitable sample size, but I understand these two may be linked.

Comment: This is a spectacular question.  But I have some questions and one concern (and they probably won't fit in one comment...so I'll break them apart).  First, ¿are you assuming that the population has some existing count/ranking of the 100 items?  If so, ¿how are you envisioning this ranking/counting?  For example, you could have a ranking by how many people chose each option for the 1st, 2nd, ... 100th place (a large matrix).  Or, you could just focus on what % of people choose each option 1st (or in the top 3 or top 10 etc).

Comment: The second question is about what you are trying to capture form the samples.  In particular, ¿do you want to capture the rankings or the multinomial probabilities for being first for each item or the population ranked voting matrix?

Comment: And for my concern, there is something from voting theory called The Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives (IIA) criteria.  In brief, a pairwise comparison like this is subject to violating this criteria.  The basic idea is that if you have one item ranked above the others, then it should stay above the others if an irrelevant alternative is introduced.  The problem here is that as your # of items gets larger...the number of possible IIAs increases the chances of violating this.

Comment: @GreggH Thanks for your questions. Yes I am assuming that there is an intrinsic rank of each of the 100 items. So if you had an infinite number of comparisons then one would find the "true" ranking. I guess one can think as it as, the item with rank 1 is the one that most people agree is better than all the others. In terms of how I will construct the final ranking, I will probably use something like the ELO rating or rank centrality. I am only interested in how close the final ranking is to the "true ranking".

Comment: Can you exclude ties that leave no winners, that is, for a hypothetical example with three items and three users, you get rankings A>B>C, B>C>A and C>A>B?

Comment: There is one other point that needs to be clarified.  You are asking about the necessary sample size, but there is the issue of the number of comparisons presented to each of the participants.  That is to say, ¿are you looking for the necessary sample size for all possible $4950 = \frac{100·99}2$ comparisons? or ¿are you assuming that each respondent is only seeing a subset of the possible comparisons (in which case, you need to determine 2 sample sizes)?

Comment: The idea is basically to run a pairwise comparison survey to determine the ranking of the items. It is infeasible to collect all combinations, so the actual number of comparisons is ideally much lower than the number of total combinations. However, the question is how much lower? If there are 4950 total combinations, are 500 comparisons enough? 1000? How do I choose this number in a rigorous sense? If one choose 1000 comparisons, it could be divided across 10 participants such that each answers 100 comparisons.